# How to simulate a logged api in django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom login_required decorator,

```
def login_required(func):
  def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.siteuser: 
      return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
      return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'error': request.siteuser_exception, 'error_code': 401}), status=401)

  return wrapper
```

then I want to call the user_info view with an api, how to create this api?

```
url(r'^info$', 'user_info')

@login_required
def user_info(request):
  return request.siteuser
```

Comment: What do you mean "with an api"? And how it connected with the custom login decorator?

Comment: I mean "by the api". I've worked it out, the http request header need to contain parameter "token".

Comment: I still can't understand the question =) "how to create this api?", 'simulate a logged api in django?' - can you formulate it more precisely?

Comment: Sorry about that, my English is not so good.

Comment: I want to say is: I want to use an api to access a decorated after long_required view function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to authenticate API user via some token os something else.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
# default authentication
# user = authenticate(username, password)
user = User.objects.get(custom_filter_that_finds_user=...) 
if user:
    login(request, user)  # this call sets authorizing cookies and makes this user "authorized"
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests